# How to run my custom code before a cron job (catalogrule_apply_all) WITHOUT overriding Magento's core?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cron, magento-cron

Plain and simple: my module must do *stuff* before Magento's own `catalogrule_apply_all` (meaning: `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule::dailyCatalogUpdate()`).

I see no event rised neither in this method itself nor in its invoked method `Mage::getSingleton('catalogrule/rule')::applyAll()`.

I'd strongly would prefer NOT to override the module because... this is a awful practice.

So... **is there a way to run my code before a Magento's other job without overriding?**